# SQL check if table exist and truncate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to code a statement that checks if a table exist and if it does to truncate/delete it. If it doesn't exist, to print the message 'This table does not exist!'

This is what I've come up so far but doesn't seem to work.

```
BEGIN
         TRUNCATE TABLE PPA_P6_2018;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('This table does not exist!');
            ELSE
                RAISE;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('This table has been delted!');
            END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't seem to work" means.  Are you getting an error?  Is it not working in some way?

Comment: with the statement i've got, it get a syntax error for 'table'. Is there a better way of doing this

Comment: you should consider using ALL_OBJECTS to determine the existence of your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DECLARE
    v_count        NUMBER;
    v_table_name   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'YOURTABLE';
    v_sqlstr       VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
    SELECT   COUNT ( * )
      INTO   v_count
      FROM   user_tables
     WHERE   table_name = v_table_name;

    IF v_count > 0
    THEN
        v_sqlstr := 'DELETE FROM ' || v_table_name;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sqlstr;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            'TABLE ' || v_table_name || ' HAS BEEN DELETED!');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('TABLE ' || v_table_name || ' DOES NOT EXIST!');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom exception to catch when the table does not exist and then only catch that single exception (rather than catching all of them with `OTHERS`) and then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to truncate/drop the table:

```sql
DECLARE
  table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'PPA_P6_2018';
  table_not_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( table_not_exists, -942 );
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || table_name;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('This table has been deleted!');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN table_not_exists THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('This table does not exist!');
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=564c9934f5de1077d15fb025d35ebcb3)

Comment: If you're going to drop the table, what's the point in truncating it first?

Comment: @AndyDan The OP asked "I'm trying to code a statement that checks if a table exist and if it does to truncate/delete it." This included code for both options; use whichever is appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 2):

`TRUNCATE TABLE` is DDL so cannot be run directly within PL/SQL.  You need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE PPA_P6_2018';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('This table does not exist!');
        ELSE
            RAISE;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('This table has been delted!');
        END IF;
END;
```

Note: You will never see the message 'This table has been delted!' since the RAISE before it throws you out of the block!  And if you got an error, the table **hasn't** been deleted anyway!

Comment: I've tried this, however it doesn't find the table name and prints that it does not exist

Comment: In that case, table PPA_P6_2018 indeed does not exist in the schema you are running this in.