# creating table if not exist pl/sql with oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

i need to create a script that do this thing:

check if the table exists, if exists truncate(or drop and create) table else create that table. i try to search on internet but some code work for half or not work at all.

this is one of script i found on internet

```
DECLARE
  val INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO val FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'tabella';
  IF val = 1 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('TRUNCATE TABLE tabella');
  ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE TABLE tabella(idTabella INTEGER NOT NULL, campo VARCHAR(50)');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Pay attention to upper/lower case in table name, there are many answers about this. In your code, I believe it would be enough to use the uppercase name ( `… = 'TABELLA'`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL check if table exist and truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658067/sql-check-if-table-exist-and-truncate)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check if the table exists; just try to truncate the table and if the table does not exist then catch the exception and create the table:

```sql
DECLARE
  table_not_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( table_not_exists, -942 );
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE tabella';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'truncated' );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN table_not_exists THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE tabella ( idTabella INTEGER NOT NULL, campo VARCHAR(50) )';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'created' );
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dda2fe157b6b5ad217bc6554b15d81a2)

Answer (score 0):

Since table names are saved as upper case strings, you should check them the same case. There are to ways you can do this:

1. You can write your table name in upper case like:

`SELECT COUNT(*) INTO val FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'TABELLA';`

2. You can lower case your table_name column so you can input it lower case all the time:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables WHERE LOWER(table_name) = 'tabella';`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The database defaults all names to UPPER_CASE. When you execute

```
CREATE TABLE tabella(...
```

the database actually creates the table with a name of `TABELLA`. This is fine - unless you quote the name of an object, by surrounding it in double-quotes, the database will automatically convert all names to upper case, and everything will work just fine. The only time you need to remember to use UPPER_CASE names is when you're accessing system tables or views, such as USER_TABLES. If  you change the query in your script to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO val FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'TABELLA';
```

I think you'll find it works just fine.